# HTML5 appcache : Refresh clears manifest

Tags: html, html5-appcache

The manifest is getting cleared from the browser once I refresh the page.

This is the manifest :

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# Cache manifest – version & date
# version 2.1.26
# 02.11.2013

# Cache – resources to cache with html page
CACHE:
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
css/stylesheet.css
css/jquery.handsontable.full.css
css/bootstrap.css
css/bootstrap.min.css
css/bootstrap.min.org.css
css/bootstrap-responsive.css
css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css
css/jquery.handsontable.bootstrap.css
img/logo.png
img/glyphicons-halflings.png
img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
js/workbook.js
js/jquery.handsontable.full.js
js/jquery.js
js/jquery.chained.js
js/bootstrap.min.js
js/bootstrap.js
# Images/HTML5LogoSmall.png



# Network – files that will not be cached and will always be online
# Following resources require network connection.
# * - it’s a special flag to indicate all urls should be whitelisted (meaning all resources that are not cached will require a connection.)
NETWORK:
http://*
https://*


# Fallback – display for all uncached pages/resources [precedence below Network]
# FALLBACK:
#site/images/ images/offline.jpg
#*.html offline.html
```

What am i missing? why manifest getting cleared?

UPDATE:
1) Using chrome as web browser
2) Hosted the application on IIS7

Comment: What do you mean with "getting cleared"? Is it loaded empty? Is the cache invalidated when it shouldn't? I cannot give an answer until you clarify the question.

Comment: @ayke the cache is getting loaded first time when i go online and its not empty.During offline if i refresh its getting cleared.

Comment: Yeah, I know what happens on the first load. But what happens exactly on refresh? "Getting cleared" is open to interpretation.

Comment: Just in case you haven't, I recommend reading this article: http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag